# How can I install Ubuntu packages insted of PyPi in setup?

Tags: python, setuptools

I just made a Python package with setuptool, but I face a problem, If I preinstall everything from the Ubuntu repository the its working, but when I'm using PyPi the installation fails because on the PyPi contains only the source and it has to be compiled, so there are a lot of error source during installation. How can I install Ubuntu package during my package installation? My idea is the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), is there a better way?

**EDITED**

The error message

```
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/enable/
Reading http://code.enthought.com/projects/enable
Best match: enable 4.2.0
Downloading http://www.enthought.com/repo/ets/enable-4.2.0.tar.gz
Processing enable-4.2.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-wuMg8s/enable-4.2.0/setup.cfg
Running enable-4.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-wuMg8s/enable-4.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-LbjqHY
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:548: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/local/include/python2.7 is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:548: UserWarning: Specified path  is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
Warning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a library freetype2_srcWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a library agg24_srcWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add a library kiva_srcWarning: distutils distribution has been initialized, it may be too late to add an extension _agg/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:548: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/X11R6/lib is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:548: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/X11/lib is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:548: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/X11R6/include is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:548: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/X11/include is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
error: X11 libraries not found.
```

Setup script:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup( 
    name = 'SomeName',
    version = '0.1',
    packages = ['src'],
    author = 'Some Author',
    maintainer = 'Some',
    maintainer_email = 'some@email.com',
    description = '',
    url = 'www.some.com',
    install_requires = ['envisage >= 4.0',
                        'pyface >= 4.0',
                        'apptools >= 4.0',
                        'chaco >= 4.0',
                        'traits >= 4.0',
                        'traitsui >= 4.0',
                        'mysql-connector-python >= 1.0',
                        'pysnmp >= 4.2',
                        'pyasn1 >= 0.1.4',
                        'M2Crypto >= 0.21.1',
                        'netifaces >= 0.7'

                        ],
 )
```

Comment: Installation from PyPi should work fine. I think you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Possibly if you provide the error information, it may be helpful for us.

Comment: I posted the error messgae

Comment: Can you also post your setup.py script?

Comment: It is just a simple setup, I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing from apt repositories the binaries downloaded are already built with the required system libraries.  If not, the apt manager ensures that any system libraries are also installed. Installing using setuptools (pip or easy_install) only fetch the *python* requirements; and not the build/system requirements.

In your case, the error is `error: X11 libraries not found.`  This means that the build headers for X11 are not available in your system.  An easy way to get around this is to tell apt to only download and install the dependencies for your package (and not the package itself). This will ensure that when you use pip or easy_install, Python will find everything it needs.

For example, `psycopg2` is the Python library for Postgresql. To build it, you need postgresql support libraries (headers and files). These are not available from PyPi. The debian package `python-psycopg2` will properly install all the external requirements.  Now if I want to install psycopg2 in a virtual environment, I first need to make sure my system has all the external requirements to build the package, so I run this command:

`sudo apt-get build-dep python-pyscopg2`

This will only install the dependencies (all supporting headers) so that I can manually install it later.

In your case, you should run `apt-get build-dep python-enable`, and it will fetch everything required:

```
# apt-get build-dep python-enable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cdbs libblas3gf libdrm-intel1 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libfreetype6-dev
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa
  libglu1-mesa-dev liblapack3gf libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpthread-stubs0
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdamage1
  libxdmcp-dev libxfixes3 libxslt1.1 libxxf86vm1 mesa-common-dev
  python-chardet python-docutils python-lxml python-numpy python-pygments
  python-pyrex python-roman python-setupdocs python-sphinx swig x11-common
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xtrans-dev
0 upgraded, 40 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 35.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 97.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Once all those libraries are installed, your pypi package will install correctly.

PyPi is only for Python packages (and Python-specific dependencies for those packages). For any external requirements; you need to specify those in your install documentation or have them available on the system so that the install process can succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, That was clear for me, my question is how can I include `apt-get` in the setup script?

Comment: You can't. It is only for packages available from PyPi. You can create a custom shell script to install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this modified script:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup( 
    name = 'SomeName',
    version = '0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    author = 'Some Author',
    maintainer = 'Some',
    maintainer_email = 'some@email.com',
    description = '',
    url = 'www.some.com',
    install_requires = ['envisage',
                        'pyface',
                        'apptools',
                        'chaco',
                        'traits',
                        'traitsui',
                        'mysql-connector-python',
                        'pysnmp4',
                        'pyasn1',
                        'm2crypto',
                        'netifaces'

                        ],
 )
```